# for loop with several consecutive setTimeout calls not repeating correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short, i'm working in the *chrome developer console* and i have a javascript function (that i decided to call main for illustration) that makes 4 function calls but each of the 4 function calls need to be separated by a few seconds to allow the page to update properly and the user to react to the resulting dialogue boxes.

The main function WORKS beautifully when i add a setTimeout with a delay to each of the 4 function calls inside and run it ONCE. it does NOT work when i try to loop the main function X times.

From what i can gather from reading other similar problems and documentation, this has to do with the complexities of how setTimeout works and how the javascript engine in the chrome browser is single-threaded... or something? Not my expertise but i tried to do my due diligence, ultimately i do not know how to fix the problem and even searching other Q/A's and documentation i could not arrive at a working solution

I've tried the below code with the setTimeout( , delay * i) method and with the setTimeout( , delay) with no index from the for loop being passed in to multiply the delay, both did not work correctly.

Other questions recommend using nested setTimeouts, i'm not sure how to accomplish that here? and others recommend using setInterval, but i'm not sure how to accomplish that a programmatic amount of times, as each of my surveys has a certain number of questions, and i don't want the number of repetitions of the main function to exceed the maximum amount of questions in a survey.

```
for(let i = 1; i < 15+1; i++) {
    main(i);
}


function main(i){
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000*i);
    setTimeout(checkforanswers,5000*i);    
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 8000*i);
    setTimeout(function(){$("[name=next_question_button]")[0].click();},11000*i);

}
```

The main function is supposed to loop an arbitrary number of times each time, and in my head, the program flow is supposed to be:

1. execute the "takescreenshot" function after a 2 second delay from executing main.
2. execute the "checkforanswers" function 5 seconds after main is called and 3 seconds after the first function is called in main. this gap between step 1-2 allows the user to respond to the print dialogue box that arises.
   3.execute the "takescreenshot" function 8 seconds after main is called, and 3 seconds after the previous step, allowing the page DOM elements to be updated correctly for the new screenshot to reflect changes from the first screen shot.
3. execute a click on the "next_question" button to advance to the next question in my survey, 11 seconds after main is called and 3 seconds after the last screen shot is taken to advance onto the next question, allowing 4 steps to be repeated on a new question of the survey.

When executed once, it works exactly as I want, but when looped multiple times, step 1-4 begin to occur without the proper delay and start to happen before the relevant "wait for X" in each of the steps has been satisfied and it all mushes together achieving unpredictable and unwanted results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is off. You should be multiplying `i` by the *time it takes for a full iteration to complete*, and then adding 2, 5, or 8 seconds to it instead. For example, if the desired time from one iteration's `takescreenshot` to the next iteration's `takescreenshot` is 14000 ms, use:

```
function main(i){
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000 + (i * 14000));
    setTimeout(checkforanswers,5000 + (i * 14000));    
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 8000 + (i * 14000));
    setTimeout(function(){$("[name=next_question_button]")[0].click();},11000 + (i * 14000));
}
```

The order of operations would be clearer if you promisified the function and `await`ed each call in the `for` loop:

```
(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 15 + 1; i++) {
    await main();
  }
})();


function main() {
  setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000);
  setTimeout(checkforanswers, 5000);
  setTimeout(takescreenshot, 8000);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("[name=next_question_button]")[0].click();
      resolve();
    }, 11000);
  });
}
```

Comment: This solution and the above solution by "t.niese" both worked to solve my problem. Essentially i thought i was implementing a solution like the "await" solution proposed above, where the main loop wouldn't start the next iteration until everything was resolved, but i ended up originally implementing a solution like "t.niese" provided but my algorithm was incorrect. Thanks to both of you and other commenters!

Answer (score 1):

If `i` is `2` then `setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000*i);` will be called `2000*2` milliseconds after main was called.

But you want that it is called `11000 + 2000` milliseconds after main was called. The same is for the other timeouts.

As `i` starts with `1` you want to use `11000 * (i - 1)` as a delay added to each timeout function.

```
function main(i){
    let delay = 11000 * (i - 1);
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000 + delay );
    setTimeout(checkforanswers, 5000 + delay );    
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 8000 + delay );
    setTimeout(function(){$("[name=next_question_button]")[0].click();}, 11000 + delay);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the classic chunking approach:

```
function chunks([first, ...other], delay = 2000, result) {
  const nextResult = first(result);
  setTimeout(() => chunks(other, delay, nextResult), delay);
}

const simpleFunction = () => { return 'whatever'; };
const functionWithParams = (a, b) => a + b;

const pipe = [
  simpleFunction,
  () => functionWithParams(3, 5),
  data => console.log('inline code to run, which uses prev result (3+5=8): ' + data),
];

chunks(pipe);
// or chunks(pipe, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop does not wait so you are just making timeout calls that are milliseconds apart for the entire loop. So you are basically calling `takescreenshot` 15 times. 
Just use main to call itself. In the last timeout, call main to repeat.

```
function main(i){
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 2000*i);
    setTimeout(checkforanswers,5000*i);    
    setTimeout(takescreenshot, 8000*i);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("[name=next_question_button]")[0].click();}
      if (i<14) {
        main(i+1)
      }
    }, 11000*i)
}

main(0)
```